# python re finding in string

Tags: python, regex, string

im trying to do a kind of basic AI for a school project using python's re, and i wanted to ask is there a way to determine if given pattern exists in string, like

```
string = raw_input()

"""I type in 'Hey can you check the weather?' """
```

and if it does find word 'weather' it returns true or false.

I would then use it to run through series of if statements, to chceck what the user wants to do(like weather, date, time, and other things).

Also, i would be very happy to hear from you guys if u had better idea of solving this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need `regex` for such simple checks. Simply use `in` to check for given word in your sentence as:

```
>>> my_string = 'Hey can you check the weather?'
>>> 'weather' in my_string
True
```

So, in order to check from list of words, you may use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) as:

```
>>> words_to_check = ['hello', 'world', 'weather']
>>> any(word in my_string for word in words_to_check)
True
```

As mentioned by *@DYZ*, in order to do case in-sensitive match, you need to make a check on the lowercased string as:

```
# Converts string to lowercase  v
>>> any(word in my_string.lower() for word in words_to_check)
True
```

Comment: Since the word in the string can be in upper of mixed string, the string has to be first converted to the lower case: `any(word in my_string for word in words_to_check.lower())`

Comment: @DYZ I think you mean `any(word in my_string.lower() for word in words_to_check)`

Comment: Correct, that's what I mean.